# GridBagLayout anchoring is not working, always showing in the JPanel in center

Tags: java, swing

My application is in fullscreen exclusive mode, i want the JPanel mainPanel to be in LAST_LINE_START with some padding to the left and right. but when i run this program it only shows the mainPanel in center of the screen. I tried other positions also, but they did not work either.

```
private void mainWindow()
    {   
        gls =(JPanel) mainUi.getGlassPane();
        gls.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
        nwGame = new JButton("New Game");
        nwGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                gls.setVisible(false);
                startGame(0);
                mainUi.repaint();
            }
        });

        ldGame = new JButton("Load Game");
        ldGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {

            }
        });

        changeProfile = new JButton("Change Profile");
        changeProfile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {

            }
        });

        qtGame = new JButton("Quit Game");
        qtGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {

            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.ipadx = 10;
        gbc.ipady = 10;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;

        mainPanel.add(nwGame);
        mainPanel.add(ldGame);
        mainPanel.add(changeProfile);
        mainPanel.add(qtGame);

        gls.add(mainPanel,gbc);
        gls.setVisible(true);

        mainUi.add(gls);
        if(!mainUi.isVisible())
            mainUi.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: This is the default behaviour of `GridBagLayout`.  It will want to place all the components within the center of the container...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I see...

> it only shows the mainPanel in center of the screen

...associated with GridBagLayout, I always look first to see how the user is implementing the weightx and weighty GridBagConstraint properties, and as expected, you aren't. Use them.

i.e.,

```
   GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
   gbc.ipadx = 10;
   gbc.ipady = 10;
   gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
   gbc.weightx = 1.0;
   gbc.weighty = 1.0;
```